# Swift 3.0 : Use Legacy Swift Language Version

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I am new to Swift and I want to understand the "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" means. I googled a lot everyone only gives an answer as fix not the meaning like why it is used and what is meaning.

If I checked Use Legacy Swift Language Version then we have 3 options:
1. YES
2. NO 
3. Unspecified

What is their meaning?
Suppose I selected Yes. Then what is the meaning and why I choose Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Use legacy swift version means you can use either Swift 2.3 or Swift 3.x for your code.

If you want to work with new project and you want to work with Legacy code (Swift 2.3) or 3.0 then you can do settings from build settings as follows :

[image]

Default Setting is No (Swift 3). But if you want to do legacy code (Swift 2.3) then you have to select Yes (Swift 2.3).

For more infomation : [Steps to use Legacy Swift in Xcode 8](http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/09/steps-to-use-legacy-swift-in-xcode-8/)

You can also check : https://swift.org/migration-guide/